# Element unselectable with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a div in a page that I can't select with jQuery. I've tried selecting by ID and by class, with

```
alert(jQuery(".warningmessage").size());
```

and

```
alert($("#" + warningId).size());
```

but both return 0. The only thing I can think of that might have an effect is that the content containing the element was loaded with Ajax, or maybe there's a syntax error on the page, although I can inspect it with Firebug and see the element there.

The page is part of an app so you have to log in to see it but I can post a demo login username/password if necessary.

The HTML is

```
<div class="warningmessage" id="rdvg2pgrktrbdw8um_warning"></div>
```

Comment: Your code is correct so - what is the question?

Comment: You know that jQuery won't cross down into an `<iframe>` from the outer page, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not provided enough details to receive a precise answer.

I would guess that your script is running before the page loads.
Move the `<script>` block to the bottom of the page.
Alternatively, wrap the code in `$(function() { ... })`.

Comment: I don't think either of these work since it's it's loaded via AJAX, the element would still be loaded later than this runs.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the content was originally loaded over Ajax, when the function containing the selection code is run, the content is definitely there - I can see it on screen. Selection is triggered by a keypress.

Comment: It's this by the way:

<div class="warningmessage" id="rdvg2pgrktrbdw8um_warning"></div>

Comment: @Oliver - If `alert($(".warningmessage").size())` is 0, it's an ordering issue, did you try running it in the console?

Comment: Is the `<div>` in question possibly loaded into an `<iframe>`, while the button and the code are *outside* the `<iframe>`?

Comment: That could be it. The div is in an iframe, the javaScript that calls it is both in the <head> of that iframe content and in the enclosing page. I'll look into it...

Comment: That was it. Thanks! Solved by getting the frame's document as a jQuery object and running .find(".warningmessage") on it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot find an element until *after* it's loaded, otherwise what are you finding?

For instance, you can do the call in your `success` method (this is an example, anywhere that runs **after** it's inserted into the DOM works), something like this:

```
$.ajax({
   // ...options...
   success: function(data) {
     //insert elements, including `#warningId`
     alert($("#warningId").size());
   }
});
```

If you're looking for a generic one, say any particular ajax call you might be bringing back a `.warningmessage` element, something like the [`.ajaxSuccess()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) method may be a better approach, like this:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
  $(".warningmessage").fadeIn();
});
```

If it's not a server-side warning and an actual error in the AJAX request itself you want to handle, check out the corresponding [`.ajaxError()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) event handler.